# Boundedness of differential equation without solving?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have a differential equation $$f'(x)=x-f(x)^2$$ subject to $$f(0)=0,x\geq0$$ How can I show that for each $x, f(x)$ is bounded by $$0\leq f(x)\leq \sqrt{x}$$
My attempt at solution: Let $\epsilon >0$ be given, and let $f_\epsilon$ be the Euler approximation of $f$ with step size $\epsilon$. I then tried to show by induction that for each positive integer $n$, $f_\epsilon ((n+1)\epsilon)\geq f_\epsilon (n\epsilon)$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this proves that $f$ is monotonically increasing, so $f'(x)\geq0$ for every $x\geq0$, and the result follows immediately from there. However, I cannot get my induction to work properly and feel like I am barking up the wrong tree. What approach should I take to attack this problem?

Answer (score 2):

(1) Show that $f(x) = x^2/2 + O(x^3)$.  So for $x>0$ sufficiently small, $\sqrt{x} > f(x) > 0$.

(2) If ever $f(x) = 0$ with $x > 0$, $f'(x) > 0$.  Conclude $f(x)$ can never hit $0$ for $x > 0$.

(3) If ever $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ with $x > 0$, $f'(x) = 0$ so $\dfrac{d}{dx} (f(x) - \sqrt{x}) < 0$.  Conclude $f(x)$ can never hit $\sqrt{x}$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: Hi! What does $O(x^3)$ mean?

Comment: @user5583511 it represents a quantity which is smaller than $ Cx^3 $ for some positive constant $ C $ and $ x $ sufficiently close to zero.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this exercise in analysis. Then take $\alpha  = \sqrt[2]t$.